# Delay until jQuery animate has finished

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-animate

I have made a jQuery plugin which makes a splash screen. It uses the animate function of jQuery and is initalized and fired by the following:

```
    $('#temperature_splash').splashScreen();

    $('.tempGraphButton').click(function () {

        $('#temperature_splash').splashScreen('splash', 300);

         //Here, I would like to make an ajax request when the animation has finished
    }
```

I would like to make an ajax request after the animations in the plugin has finished but I don't know how. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Outline of the plugin code

```
$.fn.splashScreen = function (method) {
    // Method calling logic
    if (methods[method]) {
        return methods[method].apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
    } else if (typeof method === 'object' || !method) {
        return methods.init.apply(this, arguments);
    } else {
        $.error('Method ' + method + ' does not exist');
    }
}

var methods = {
    init: function () {
        //Some initializations
    },

    splash: function (time) {
        //Setting some properties

        splashScreenContent.animate({
            width: width,
            left: leftPos
        }, time).animate({
            height: height,
            top: topPos
        }, time);

        return false;
    }
}

})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just add a callback

```
var methods = {
    init: function () {
        methods.splash(1000, function() {
            //do something when animation is finished
            methods.ajax();
        });
    },
    splash: function (time, callback) {
        splashScreenContent.animate({
            width: width,
            left: leftPos
        }, time).animate({
            height: height,
            top: topPos
        }, time, function() {
            if (typeof callback==='function') callback.call();
        });

        return false;
    },
    ajax: function() {
        //do ajax stuff
    }
}
```

It's just an example, you'll have to figure out what options to pass and how to tie it into your plugin yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you also tie into the .done feature in jQuery?

`methods.done(function(){  do your code here for the ajax })'`

Comment: A self made plugin does'nt necessarily have access to promises, unless you add it in the plugin.

Answer (score 0):

as these calls are asynchronous, you can put your ajax code just before closing of splash code as code after splash function would be executed before the code inside the splash function